# Convert List to Page in spring data mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mvc-test

I am really struggling to convert `List<User> users` to `Page<User>` in spring data mongo? Note `Page` is an API from `org.springframework.data.domain.Page`;

I am using `Pagination` of Spring Data Mongo, so I need to sent `Page<User>` and not the `List<User>` .

How we can get Pages from List if I don't want to use `Page<>` repository method?

Please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it in following way. It very simple implementation and works fine for me.

```
Page<User> usersPage = new PageImpl<User>(users,pageable, users.size());
```